# How to specify what django view to display when a process ends?

Tags: django-viewflow

If I've understood the viewflow code correctly, when a flow reaches its end node, the function get_next_task_url from viewflow.flow.views.utils redirects to the process detail page or the process index page.

It would be great if the End node allowed us to specify what view to redirect to at the end of the process. For example, it would be great in a flow object to be able to write something like:

```
end = flow.End(redirect='app:view',args=...,kwargs=...)
```

And then get_next_task_url could redirect as specified.

Perhaps it would be possible to subclass the existing End node to achieve this - any pointers how to achieve this would be most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Mm, yep, there is no such functionality on the end node, since it could be triggered not only by a person task. To override redirect path, just do it in your task view, like you will do with pure Django.